# Residue of $f(z) = \frac{z-1}{1+\cos(\pi z)}$ at $z=2k+1$

Tags: complex-analysis

How can i compute the residue of:

$$f(z) = \frac{z-1}{1+\cos(\pi z)}$$

at $z_k=2k+1, k\neq 0$.

Comment: @Did Good. So, I will delete the comments. Why not edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $w=z-(2k+1)$, then at $z=2k+1$, $w=0$.
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{w+(2k+1)-1}{1-\cos(\pi w)}
&=(w+(2k+1)-1)\frac1{\frac{\pi^2}{2}w^2+O\left(w^4\right)}\\
&=(w+2k)\frac1{w^2}\left(\frac2{\pi^2}+O\left(w^2\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{4k}{\pi^2}\frac1{w^2}+\frac2{\pi^2}\frac1w+O(1)
\end{align}
$$
Thus, the residue at $w=0$, aka $z=2k+1$, is $\frac2{\pi^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Points $z_k=2k+1$ are poles of order $2$ for $f(z) = \dfrac{z-1}{1+\cos(\pi z)}$ with residues
$$\operatorname{res}\limits_{z=z_k}{f(z)}=\lim\limits_{z\to{z_k}}\dfrac{d}{dz}{\left(\dfrac{(z-z_k)^2 (z-1)}{1+\cos{\pi z}}\right)} = \dfrac{2}{\pi^{2}}.$$

Comment: yes i know this, and i tried to use a formula like $\lim_{z\rightarrow z_k}\frac{d}{dz}[(z-z_k)^2f(z)]$, but i think i may use series expansion: i get $f(z)=\frac{z-z_k}{(z-z_k)^2[\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\ldots]}+\frac{2k}{(z-z_k)^2[\frac{\pi^2}{2}-\ldots]}$. Can i conclude now that the residue is $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$?

Comment: @FedericaMaggioni: substitution makes the notation cleaner. I use the series expansion and [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) in my answer.